# changing state before next keydown in react

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

I am creating a game that when your health goes below 0, on a keydown it prints in a div:
 "Game_over_:(_click_to_continue" letter by letter. I was getting a bug where the letters would print out multiple times like ggggaaammmeee  ooovvveerr.

I set up a conditional statement where if the state gameOver is 0 and after a keydown event, then it activates the setInterval, else it does not. That solved the problem to some extent, however, the state sometimes changes a second late, and after setting up console.log(this.state.gameOver), it sometimes prints 0 twice before this.state.gameOver actually changes to 1. Other times it works just fine.

```
if (this.state.gameOver===0){
 console.log(this.state.gameOver)
 var s1="Game_Over\n:(\nClick_to_continue..." 
 var v1 =0
 var b = document.getElementById("redButton")
 var arr1 = setInterval(function(){ 
 if(v1===0){b.innerText=""};b.innerText= b.innerText+s1[v1];v1+=1; 
 if(v1==s1.length){clearInterval(arr1)}}, 100)


 this.setState({gameOver:1})

}
```

It's still sometimes printing Ggaammee Ovveerr.

Comment: Remember one thing react re-renders once the state is set

Comment: but the first keydown event triggers the code above, which changes the state of gameOver to 1,  and if it does rerender, why is the  second keydown event still outputting gameOver to be equal to zero?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you are setting the inner text of the div element and not using ReactJS and its DOM render method to display the "game over" text?

Comment: im not sure how you would incorporate the setTimeout function with a reactjs dom element to print out one letter at a time

Comment: I agree with @Padmika. You could have a setTimeout that would update the state one character at a time and then use the react render rather than the getElementById.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So all I had to do was set up a conditional statement that depends on whether a variable is true or false. Once the setInterval function is triggered, the variable changes to false so that more keydowns wont cause multiple calls to setInterval.

```
var check;

if (check!==false){ 

check=false;
var arr1 = setInterval(function(){
if(v1===0){b.innerText=""};
b.innerText= b.innerText+s1[v1];v1+=1; 
if(v1==s1.length){clearInterval(arr1)}}, 100)}
```

Once I click the screen with the mouse:

```
check=true;
```